# Socket io not firing events due to if statement, maybe race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My issue seems to be the server is listening on a websocket for certain events and then when a certain event is heard it is supposed to fire its own event through a different websocket, but that event is rarely fired. With the conditional statement inside function availabilityCheck removed, the event is always fired instead of rarely. There are 2 sockets websockets the server is connected on for clarity.

event heard from websocket(1) usually 2-4 times within milliseconds-> backend does logic (but only once event though the event was fired 2-4 times) -> event supposed to fire to websocket(2)

```
let obj = {available: 0}

if (event.Event == 'AgentConnect') {
     const agentExtension = '1001'
     availabilityCheck(event, agentExtension)
     .then(function () {
         socket.emit('AgentConnect', agentExtension); //works rarely, but always works when the if statement inside availabilityCheck() is removed
     }).catch(function(err){
         console.log(err);
       })
     }// end if




function availabilityCheck(evt, agentExt) {
    return promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (obj.available == 0) {// When this conditional is removed the socket event always fires
            obj.available =1;
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject('agent unavailable');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: where is obj coming from?

Comment: not really relevant but I added it for you at the top for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
var obj = (x =>{
    var available = 0;
    return {
      set available(val) {
        debugger;
        available=val;
      },
      get available() {
        return available;
      }
    }
})();
```

Now it should pause when you change available, if you have the dev tools open (press F12) you can check the stack trace and see what other code is changing available while the Promise is resolving.

The code you provided does not show any problem, available should still be 0 but I'm sure there is more code.

If you want something to happen in serie then you could run the promise in serie instead of parallel:

```
let agentConnectPromise = Promise.resolve()

if (event.Event == 'AgentConnect') {
  agentConnectPromise =
  agentConnectPromise
  .then(
    x=> availabilityCheck(event, agentExtension)
  )
  .then(...
```

Comment: I should've been more clear. My code is trying to write to obj.available while also trying to read obj.available because availabilityCheck is being run multiple times asynchronously. Then as a result of that socket.emit('AgentConnect', agentExtension); doesnt do anything.

Comment: @HarrisonSchultz so at some point you set available back to 0? If you don't want to asynchronous processes run at the same time you can do this better by serializing them (See updated answer).

Comment: thank you. your suggestion helped me find a solution! I needed to assign the variable after the function that reads it finished.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the assignment of obj.available to the then() fixed my issue.

```
if (event.Event == 'AgentConnect') {
 const agentExtension = '1001'
 availabilityCheck(event, agentExtension)
 .then(function () {
obj.available = 1; //moved from availability to check to here.
     socket.emit('AgentConnect', agentExtension); //works rarely, but always works when the if statement inside availabilityCheck() is removed
 }).catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
   })
 }// end if
```